# Who uses Boost ASIO?

Tags: boost-asio

I would like to know how popular is Boost ASIO. 
Is it being used in any popular network-intensive software ?

Answer (score 13):

The systems software for managing an IBM [Blue Gene/Q](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Gene#Blue_Gene.2FQ) supercomputer uses Boost.Asio extensively.  The [source code](https://repo.anl-external.org/viewvc/bgq-driver/V1R2M0/) is available under the Eclipse Public License (EPL) if you're interested.

[image: Blue Gene/Q]

Comment: I know this was some time ago... but the link to the source code does not work.

Answer (score 10):

http://think-async.com/Asio/WhoIsUsingAsio

Comment: I'm frowning upon your answer. :<

Comment: Am I supposed to delete it or what? You made your point already. It's been 6 years. Get over it.

Answer (score 2):

Boost is extensively being used in serious networking software, take example of HPX uses boost libraries. HPX is implemented in C++11 and utilizes over 20 Boost and candidate Boost libraries. Have a look at http://cppnow.org/session/hpx-a-c11-parallel-runtime-system/

Also for more details you can refer [Official "Boost library" Support for Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036311/official-boost-library-support-for-android-and-ios) describing how these are being deployed on smartphone os as well.

Hope it helps!