# using multiple io_service objects

Tags: boost-asio

I have my application in which listen and process messages from both internet sockets and unix domain sockets. Now I need to add SSL to the internet sockets, I was using a single `io_service` object for all the sockets in the application. It seems now I need to add separate `io_service` objects for network sockets and unix domain sockets. I don't have any threads in my application and I use `async_send` and `async_recieve` and `async_accept` to process data and connections. Please point me to any examples using multiple `io_service` objects with async handlers.

Comment: Why can't you still use 1 `io_service`? Using multiple `io_service`s can be good for scalability purposes, but then you need to run every `io_service` in its own thread (see HTTP-2 example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)

Comment: @Igor R - can you clarify?  I have read somewhere that the I/O handlers can use multiple threads.  Are you saying that each thread that handles an async_read, for example, must use a different io_service object?

Comment: @Bob Bryan No, I said the opposite: if you use multiple `io_service`s, you usually run every one in its own thread (io_service-per-CPU approach, see the above example).

Comment: As currently worded, this question is not a good fit for SO. There won't be any single good answer for *point me at some links*. I suggest editing to rephrase your question with a specific problem.

Comment: @IgorR i am not sure how can we handle both SSL connections and non SSL connections (Unix domain sockets in my case) on single io_service object thats what the reason i was thinking about introducing one more io_service object.

Comment: I still don't understand what issue you get when passing *the same* `io_service` instance for both `tcp::socket` and `ssl::stream<tcp::socket>`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The question has a degree of uncertainty as if multiple `io_service` objects are required.  I could not locate anything in the [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) documentation, or the overview for [SSL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html) and [UNIX Domain Sockets](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html) that mandated separate `io_service` objects.  Regardless, here are a few options:

---

#### Single `io_service`:

Try to use a single `io_service`.

If you do not have a direct handle to the `io_service` object, but you have a handle to a Boost.Asio I/O object, such as a socket, then a handle to the associated `io_service` object can be obtained by calling [`socket.get_io_service()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/get_io_service.html).

---

#### Use a thread per `io_service`:

If multiple `io_service` objects are required, then dedicate a thread to each `io_service`.  This approach is used in Boost.Asio's [HTTP Server 2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server2/) example.

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service service1;
boost::asio::io_service service2;

boost::thread_group threads;
threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &service1));
service2.run();
threads.join_all();
```

One consequence of this approach is that the it may require thread-safety guarantees to be made by the application.  For example, if `service1` and `service2` both have completion handlers that invoke `message_processor.process()`, then `message_processor.process()` needs to either be thread-safe or called in a thread-safe manner.

---

#### Poll `io_service`:

[`io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) provides non-blocking alternatives to `run()`.  Where as  [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) will block until all work has finished, [`io_service::poll()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html) will run handlers that are ready to run and will not block.  This allows for a single thread to execute the event loop on multiple `io_service` objects:

```cpp
while (!service1.stopped() &&
       !service2.stopped())
{
  std::size_t ran = 0;
  ran += service1.poll();
  ran += service2.poll();
  // If no handlers ran, then sleep.
  if (0 == ran)
  {
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}
```

To prevent a tight-busy loop when there are no ready-to-run handlers, it may be worth adding in a sleep.  Be aware that this sleep may introduce latency in the overall handling of events.

---

#### Transfer handlers to a single `io_service`:

One interesting approach is to use a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) to transfer completion handlers to a single `io_service`.  This allows for a thread per `io_service`,  while preventing the need to have the application make thread-safety guarantees, as all completion handlers will post through a single service, whose event loop is only being processed by a single thread.

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service service1;
boost::asio::io_service service2;

// strand2 will be used by service2 to post handlers to service1.
boost::asio::strand strand2(service1);
boost::asio::io_service::work work2(service2);

socket.async_read_some(buffer, strand2.wrap(read_some_handler));

boost::thread_group threads;
threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &service1));
service2.run();
threads.join_all();
```

This approach does have some consequences:

- It requires handlers that are intended to by ran by the main `io_service` to be wrapped via [`strand::wrap()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html).
- The asynchronous chain now runs through two `io_service`s, creating an additional level of complexity.  It is important to account for the case where the secondary `io_service` no longer has work, causing its `run()` to return.

It is common for an asynchronous chains to occur within the same `io_service`.  Thus, the service never runs out of work, as a completion handler will post additional work onto the `io_service`.

```
   |    .------------------------------------------.
   V    V                                          |
read_some_handler()                                |
{                                                  |
  socket.async_read_some(..., read_some_handler) --'
}
```

On the other hand, when a strand is used to transfer work to another `io_service`, the wrapped handler is invoked within `service2`, causing it to post the completion handler into `service1`.  If the wrapped handler was the only work in `service2`, then `service2` no longer has work, causing `servce2.run()` to return.

```
    service1                      service2
====================================================

        .----------------- wrapped(read_some_handler)
        |                            .
        V                            .
 read_some_handler                NO WORK
        |                            .
        |                            .
        '----------------> wrapped(read_some_handler)
```

To account for this, the example code uses an [`io_service::work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) for `service2` so that `run()` remains blocked until explicitly told to [`stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are writing a server and not a client.  Don't know if this helps, but I am using ASIO to communicate with 6 servers from my client.  It uses TCP/IP SSL/TSL.  You can find a link to the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434753/boost-asio-multiple-client-connections-to-different-servers/15438408#15438408)

You should be able to use just one io_service object with multiple socket objects.  But, if you decide that you really want to have multiple io_service objects, then it should be fairly easy to do so.  In my class, the io_service object is static.  So, just remove the static keyword along with the logic in the constructor that only creates one instance of the io_service object.  Depending on the number of connections expected for your server, you would probably be better off using a thread pool dedicated to handling socket I/O rather than creating a thread for each new socket connection.