# Using a boost::asio::deadline_timer per thread not working

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio

I'm newbie here, so if I have any errors just tell me.

The problem is that I have two processes and I want them to execute concurrently because they take too much time. So I thought to implement a class `timer` which manage its own `boost::asio::io_service` and create a thread for this `io_service`. The code is the following:

timer.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class timer
{
public:
    timer(std::function<void(void)> task,
          int time)
    : io__(),
      timer__(io__, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(time)),
      repetitive_task__(task),
      time_wait__(time)
    {
          timer__.async_wait(boost::bind(&timer::loop, this));
    }

    void start()
    {
        thread__ = std::thread([this](){ 
            io__.run(); 
        });
        thread__.join();
    }

    void loop()
    {
        repetitive_task__();
        timer__.expires_at(timer__.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(time_wait__));
        timer__.async_wait(boost::bind(&timer::loop, this));
    }

    void stop()
    {
        timer__.cancel();
        io__.stop();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io__;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer__;
    std::function<void(void)> repetitive_task__;
    int time_wait__;
    std::thread thread__;
};
```

For testing it, I have the simplest main I could think:

main.cpp

```
#include "timer.hpp"

void test1()
{
    printf("action1 \n");
}

void test2()
{
    printf("action 2 \n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    timer timer1(&test1, 100);
    timer timer2(&test2, 50);

    timer1.start();
    timer2.start();
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is always **action1**. *Never action2*.

I've been looking for how to implement timers properly like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496950/using-multiple-io-service-objects) or in [this example of boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html), but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `thread__.join();` waits for the thread to exit.

Comment: Thanks @tkausl. I'm checking other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999432/stdthread-terminate-called-without-an-active-exception-dont-want-to-joi). How do you think I could solve my problem?

Comment: Pass the `io_service` into the timer constructor as a reference so you only have one io_service in the program.  Then call `io_service::poll()` or `io_service::run()` in the main thread.

Comment: Also, names with `__` are reserved for standard library implementations. Using them is not legal

Comment: thanks @sehe. I thought it was forbidden only at the beginning.

Comment: That too, for namespace/global symbols. But `__` is reserved anywhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier