# Why is my non blocking raw sockets program running so slowly?

Tags: c, sockets, optimization, raw

I have a program which uses `PF_PACKET` raw sockets to send `TCP SYN` packets to a list of web servers. The program reads in a file which has an IPv4 address on each line of a web server. The program is the beginnings of an attempt to connect to multiple servers in a high performance manner. However, currently the program is only sending about 10 packets/second. This despite the program using non blocking socket. It should be running orders of magnitude faster. Any ideas why it could be running so slowly.

I include a full code listing below. Warning - the code is quite long. That's because it takes a surprisingly large amount of code to get the IP and MAC address of the gateway router. The good news is you can skip all the functions before main because they just do the necessary work of getting the IP and MAC address of the router as well as the local IP address. Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>    //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include <netinet/ip.h> //Provides declarations for ip header
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
//#include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>  //htons etc
#include <time.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define PROTO_ARP 0x0806
#define ETH2_HEADER_LEN 14
#define HW_TYPE 1
#define MAC_LENGTH 6
#define IPV4_LENGTH 4
#define ARP_REQUEST 0x01
#define ARP_REPLY 0x02
#define BUF_SIZE 60
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 10000

#define debug(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");
#define info(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");
#define warn(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");
#define err(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");

static char * str_devname= NULL;
static int mode_loss     = 0;
static int c_packet_sz   = 150;
static int c_buffer_sz   = 1024*8;
static int c_buffer_nb   = 1024;
static int c_sndbuf_sz   = 0;
static int c_send_mask   = 127;
static int c_error       = 0;
static int c_mtu         = 0;
static int mode_thread   = 0;

volatile int fd_socket;
volatile int data_offset = 0;
volatile struct tpacket_hdr * ps_header_start;
volatile struct sockaddr_ll *ps_sockaddr = NULL;
volatile int shutdown_flag = 0;
int done = 0;
struct tpacket_req s_packet_req;
unsigned char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
struct arp_header *arp_resp = (struct arp_header *) (buffer + ETH2_HEADER_LEN);
char ifname[512];
char ip[512];

/* 
    96 bit (12 bytes) pseudo header needed for tcp header checksum calculation 
*/
struct pseudo_header
{
    u_int32_t source_address;
    u_int32_t dest_address;
    u_int8_t placeholder;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t tcp_length;
};


struct arp_header {
    unsigned short hardware_type;
    unsigned short protocol_type;
    unsigned char hardware_len;
    unsigned char protocol_len;
    unsigned short opcode;
    unsigned char sender_mac[MAC_LENGTH];
    unsigned char sender_ip[IPV4_LENGTH];
    unsigned char target_mac[MAC_LENGTH];
    unsigned char target_ip[IPV4_LENGTH];
};

int rtnl_receive(int fd, struct msghdr *msg, int flags)
{
    int len;

    do { 
        len = recvmsg(fd, msg, flags);
    } while (len < 0 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN));

    if (len < 0) {
        perror("Netlink receive failed");
        return -errno;
    }

    if (len == 0) { 
        perror("EOF on netlink");
        return -ENODATA;
    }

    return len;
}

static int rtnl_recvmsg(int fd, struct msghdr *msg, char **answer)
{
    struct iovec *iov = msg->msg_iov;
    char *buf;
    int len;

    iov->iov_base = NULL;
    iov->iov_len = 0;

    len = rtnl_receive(fd, msg, MSG_PEEK | MSG_TRUNC);

    if (len < 0) {
        return len;
    }

    buf = malloc(len);

    if (!buf) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    iov->iov_base = buf;
    iov->iov_len = len;

    len = rtnl_receive(fd, msg, 0);

    if (len < 0) {
        free(buf);
        return len;
    }

    *answer = buf;

    return len;
}

void parse_rtattr(struct rtattr *tb[], int max, struct rtattr *rta, int len)
{
    memset(tb, 0, sizeof(struct rtattr *) * (max + 1));

    while (RTA_OK(rta, len)) {
        if (rta->rta_type <= max) {
            tb[rta->rta_type] = rta;
        }

        rta = RTA_NEXT(rta,len);
    }
}

static inline int rtm_get_table(struct rtmsg *r, struct rtattr **tb)
{
    __u32 table = r->rtm_table;

    if (tb[RTA_TABLE]) {
        table = *(__u32 *)RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_TABLE]);
    }

    return table;
}

void print_route(struct nlmsghdr* nl_header_answer)
{
    struct rtmsg* r = NLMSG_DATA(nl_header_answer);
    int len = nl_header_answer->nlmsg_len;
    struct rtattr* tb[RTA_MAX+1];
    int table;
    char buf[256];

    len -= NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(*r));

    if (len < 0) {
        perror("Wrong message length");
        return;
    }
    
    parse_rtattr(tb, RTA_MAX, RTM_RTA(r), len);

    table = rtm_get_table(r, tb);

    if (r->rtm_family != AF_INET && table != RT_TABLE_MAIN) {
        return;
    }

    if (tb[RTA_DST]) {
        if ((r->rtm_dst_len != 24) && (r->rtm_dst_len != 16)) {
            return;
        }

        printf("%s/%u ", inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_DST]), buf, sizeof(buf)), r->rtm_dst_len);

    } else if (r->rtm_dst_len) {
        printf("0/%u ", r->rtm_dst_len);
    } else {
        printf("default ");
    }

    if (tb[RTA_GATEWAY]) {
        printf("via %s", inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_GATEWAY]), buf, sizeof(buf)));
        strcpy(ip, inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_GATEWAY]), buf, sizeof(buf)));
    }

    if (tb[RTA_OIF]) {
        char if_nam_buf[IF_NAMESIZE];
        int ifidx = *(__u32 *)RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_OIF]);

        printf(" dev %s", if_indextoname(ifidx, if_nam_buf));
    }

    if (tb[RTA_GATEWAY] && tb[RTA_OIF]) {
        char if_nam_buf[IF_NAMESIZE];
        int ifidx = *(__u32 *)RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_OIF]);

        strcpy(ifname, if_indextoname(ifidx, if_nam_buf));
    }

    if (tb[RTA_SRC]) {
        printf("src %s", inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_SRC]), buf, sizeof(buf)));
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int open_netlink()
{
    struct sockaddr_nl saddr;

    int sock = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);

    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open netlink socket");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));

    saddr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    saddr.nl_pid = getpid();

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to bind to netlink socket");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    return sock;
}

int do_route_dump_requst(int sock)
{
    struct {
        struct nlmsghdr nlh;
        struct rtmsg rtm;
    } nl_request;

    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_type = RTM_GETROUTE;
    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_DUMP;
    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_len = sizeof(nl_request);
    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_seq = time(NULL);
    nl_request.rtm.rtm_family = AF_INET;

    return send(sock, &nl_request, sizeof(nl_request), 0);
}

int get_route_dump_response(int sock)
{
    struct sockaddr_nl nladdr;
    struct iovec iov;
    struct msghdr msg = {
        .msg_name = &nladdr,
        .msg_namelen = sizeof(nladdr),
        .msg_iov = &iov,
        .msg_iovlen = 1,
    };

    char *buf;
    int dump_intr = 0;

    int status = rtnl_recvmsg(sock, &msg, &buf);

    struct nlmsghdr *h = (struct nlmsghdr *)buf;
    int msglen = status;

    printf("Main routing table IPv4\n");

    while (NLMSG_OK(h, msglen)) {
        if (h->nlmsg_flags & NLM_F_DUMP_INTR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Dump was interrupted\n");
            free(buf);
            return -1;
        }

        if (nladdr.nl_pid != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (h->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR) {
            perror("netlink reported error");
            free(buf);
        }

        print_route(h);

        h = NLMSG_NEXT(h, msglen);
    }

    free(buf);

    return status;
}


/*
 * Converts struct sockaddr with an IPv4 address to network byte order uin32_t.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int int_ip4(struct sockaddr *addr, uint32_t *ip)
{
    if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *i = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr;
        *ip = i->sin_addr.s_addr;
        return 0;
    } else {
        err("Not AF_INET");
        return 1;
    }
}

/*
 * Formats sockaddr containing IPv4 address as human readable string.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int format_ip4(struct sockaddr *addr, char *out)
{
    if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *i = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr;
        const char *ip = inet_ntoa(i->sin_addr);
        if (!ip) {
            return -2;
        } else {
            strcpy(out, ip);
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

/*
 * Writes interface IPv4 address as network byte order to ip.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int get_if_ip4(int fd, const char *ifname, uint32_t *ip) {
    int err = -1;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    if (strlen(ifname) > (IFNAMSIZ - 1)) {
        err("Too long interface name");
        goto out;
    }

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr) == -1) {
        perror("SIOCGIFADDR");
        goto out;
    }

    if (int_ip4(&ifr.ifr_addr, ip)) {
        goto out;
    }
    err = 0;
out:
    return err;
}

/*
 * Sends an ARP who-has request to dst_ip
 * on interface ifindex, using source mac src_mac and source ip src_ip.
 */
int send_arp(int fd, int ifindex, const unsigned char *src_mac, uint32_t src_ip, uint32_t dst_ip)
{
    int err = -1;
    unsigned char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    socket_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ARP);
    socket_address.sll_ifindex = ifindex;
    socket_address.sll_hatype = htons(ARPHRD_ETHER);
    socket_address.sll_pkttype = (PACKET_BROADCAST);
    socket_address.sll_halen = MAC_LENGTH;
    socket_address.sll_addr[6] = 0x00;
    socket_address.sll_addr[7] = 0x00;

    struct ethhdr *send_req = (struct ethhdr *) buffer;
    struct arp_header *arp_req = (struct arp_header *) (buffer + ETH2_HEADER_LEN);
    int index;
    ssize_t ret, length = 0;

    //Broadcast
    memset(send_req->h_dest, 0xff, MAC_LENGTH);

    //Target MAC zero
    memset(arp_req->target_mac, 0x00, MAC_LENGTH);

    //Set source mac to our MAC address
    memcpy(send_req->h_source, src_mac, MAC_LENGTH);
    memcpy(arp_req->sender_mac, src_mac, MAC_LENGTH);
    memcpy(socket_address.sll_addr, src_mac, MAC_LENGTH);

    /* Setting protocol of the packet */
    send_req->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_ARP);

    /* Creating ARP request */
    arp_req->hardware_type = htons(HW_TYPE);
    arp_req->protocol_type = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    arp_req->hardware_len = MAC_LENGTH;
    arp_req->protocol_len = IPV4_LENGTH;
    arp_req->opcode = htons(ARP_REQUEST);

    debug("Copy IP address to arp_req");
    memcpy(arp_req->sender_ip, &src_ip, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(arp_req->target_ip, &dst_ip, sizeof(uint32_t));

    ret = sendto(fd, buffer, 42, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("sendto():");
        goto out;
    }
    err = 0;
out:
    return err;
}

/*
 * Gets interface information by name:
 * IPv4
 * MAC
 * ifindex
 */
int get_if_info(const char *ifname, uint32_t *ip, char *mac, int *ifindex)
{
    debug("get_if_info for %s", ifname);
    int err = -1;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP));
    if (sd <= 0) {
        perror("socket()");
        goto out;
    }
    if (strlen(ifname) > (IFNAMSIZ - 1)) {
        printf("Too long interface name, MAX=%i\n", IFNAMSIZ - 1);
        goto out;
    }

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);

    //Get interface index using name
    if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) == -1) {
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
        goto out;
    }
    *ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    printf("interface index is %d\n", *ifindex);

    //Get MAC address of the interface
    if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) == -1) {
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
        goto out;
    }

    //Copy mac address to output
    memcpy(mac, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, MAC_LENGTH);

    if (get_if_ip4(sd, ifname, ip)) {
        goto out;
    }
    debug("get_if_info OK");

    err = 0;
out:
    if (sd > 0) {
        debug("Clean up temporary socket");
        close(sd);
    }
    return err;
}

/*
 * Creates a raw socket that listens for ARP traffic on specific ifindex.
 * Writes out the socket's FD.
 * Return 0 on success.
 */
int bind_arp(int ifindex, int *fd)
{
    debug("bind_arp: ifindex=%i", ifindex);
    int ret = -1;

    // Submit request for a raw socket descriptor.
    *fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP));
    if (*fd < 1) {
        perror("socket()");
        goto out;
    }

    debug("Binding to ifindex %i", ifindex);
    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
    memset(&sll, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = ifindex;
    if (bind(*fd, (struct sockaddr*) &sll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        goto out;
    }

    ret = 0;
out:
    if (ret && *fd > 0) {
        debug("Cleanup socket");
        close(*fd);
    }
    return ret;
}

/*
 * Reads a single ARP reply from fd.
 * Return 0 on success.
 */
int read_arp(int fd)
{
    debug("read_arp");
    int ret = -1;
    ssize_t length = recvfrom(fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    int index;
    if (length == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom()");
        goto out;
    }
    struct ethhdr *rcv_resp = (struct ethhdr *) buffer;
    if (ntohs(rcv_resp->h_proto) != PROTO_ARP) {
        debug("Not an ARP packet");
        goto out;
    }
    if (ntohs(arp_resp->opcode) != ARP_REPLY) {
        debug("Not an ARP reply");
        goto out;
    }
    debug("received ARP len=%ld", length);
    struct in_addr sender_a;
    memset(&sender_a, 0, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    memcpy(&sender_a.s_addr, arp_resp->sender_ip, sizeof(uint32_t));
    debug("Sender IP: %s", inet_ntoa(sender_a));

    debug("Sender MAC: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
          arp_resp->sender_mac[0],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[1],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[2],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[3],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[4],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[5]);

    ret = 0;

out:
    return ret;
}

/*
 *
 * Sample code that sends an ARP who-has request on
 * interface <ifname> to IPv4 address <ip>.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int test_arping(const char *ifname, const char *ip) {
    int ret = -1;
    uint32_t dst = inet_addr(ip);
    if (dst == 0 || dst == 0xffffffff) {
        printf("Invalid source IP\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int src;
    int ifindex;
    char mac[MAC_LENGTH];
    if (get_if_info(ifname, &src, mac, &ifindex)) {
        err("get_if_info failed, interface %s not found or no IP set?", ifname);
        goto out;
    }
    int arp_fd;
    if (bind_arp(ifindex, &arp_fd)) {
        err("Failed to bind_arp()");
        goto out;
    }

    if (send_arp(arp_fd, ifindex, mac, src, dst)) {
        err("Failed to send_arp");
        goto out;
    }

    while(1) {
        int r = read_arp(arp_fd);
        if (r == 0) {
            info("Got reply, break out");
            break;
        }
    }

    ret = 0;
out:
    if (arp_fd) {
        close(arp_fd);
        arp_fd = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}

unsigned short checksum2(const char *buf, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    const unsigned long long *b = (unsigned long long *) buf;

    unsigned t1, t2;
    unsigned short t3, t4;

    /* Main loop - 8 bytes at a time */
    while (size >= sizeof(unsigned long long))
    {
        unsigned long long s = *b++;
        sum += s;
        if (sum < s) sum++;
        size -= 8;
    }

    /* Handle tail less than 8-bytes long */
    buf = (const char *) b;
    if (size & 4)
    {
        unsigned s = *(unsigned *)buf;
        sum += s;
        if (sum < s) sum++;
        buf += 4;
    }

    if (size & 2)
    {
        unsigned short s = *(unsigned short *) buf;
        sum += s;
        if (sum < s) sum++;
        buf += 2;
    }

    if (size)
    {
        unsigned char s = *(unsigned char *) buf;
        sum += s;
        if (sum < s) sum++;
    }

    /* Fold down to 16 bits */
    t1 = sum;
    t2 = sum >> 32;
    t1 += t2;
    if (t1 < t2) t1++;
    t3 = t1;
    t4 = t1 >> 16;
    t3 += t4;
    if (t3 < t4) t3++;

    return ~t3;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    uint32_t size;
    size_t len;
    struct sockaddr_ll my_addr, peer_addr;
    int i_ifindex;
    int ec;
    struct ifreq s_ifr; /* points to one interface returned from ioctl */
    int tmp;
    FILE * fp;
    char server[254];
    int count = 0;
    int first_time = 1;
    int z;
    int first_mmap = 1;
    
    #define HWADDR_len 6
    #define IP_len 4
    int s,s2,i;
    struct ifreq ifr,ifr2;
    int ret = -1;
    struct rlimit lim;
    
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <INPUT_FILE>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim);
    printf("Soft: %d Hard: %d\n", (int)lim.rlim_cur, (int)lim.rlim_max);
    lim.rlim_cur = lim.rlim_max;
    
    
    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim) == -1) {
        printf("rlimit failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim);
    printf("New Soft: %d New Hard: %d\n", (int)lim.rlim_cur, (int)lim.rlim_max);
    
    int nl_sock = open_netlink();

    if (do_route_dump_requst(nl_sock) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to perfom request");
        close(nl_sock);
        return -1;
    }

    get_route_dump_response(nl_sock);

    close (nl_sock);
    
    test_arping(ifname, ip);

    
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
    strcpy(ifr2.ifr_name, ifname);
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
    ioctl(s2, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr2);
    struct sockaddr_in* ipaddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr2.ifr_addr;
    close(s);

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


    while (!done)
    {   
        fd_socket = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_NONBLOCK, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
        if(fd_socket == -1)
        {
            perror("socket");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* clear structure */
        memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        my_addr.sll_family = PF_PACKET;
        my_addr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    
        str_devname = ifname;
        //strcpy (str_devname, ifname);
        
        /* initialize interface struct */
        strncpy (s_ifr.ifr_name, str_devname, sizeof(s_ifr.ifr_name));
    
        /* Get the broad cast address */
        ec = ioctl(fd_socket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &s_ifr);
        if(ec == -1)
        {
            perror("iotcl");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* update with interface index */
        i_ifindex = s_ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    
        s_ifr.ifr_mtu = 7200;
        /* update the mtu through ioctl */
        ec = ioctl(fd_socket, SIOCSIFMTU, &s_ifr);
        if(ec == -1)
        {
            perror("iotcl");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* set sockaddr info */
        memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        my_addr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
        my_addr.sll_protocol = ETH_P_ALL;
        my_addr.sll_ifindex = i_ifindex;
    
        /* bind port */
        if (bind(fd_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) == -1)
        {
            perror("bind");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* prepare Tx ring request */
        s_packet_req.tp_block_size = c_buffer_sz;
        s_packet_req.tp_frame_size = c_buffer_sz;
        s_packet_req.tp_block_nr = c_buffer_nb;
        s_packet_req.tp_frame_nr = c_buffer_nb;
    
        /* calculate memory to mmap in the kernel */
        size = s_packet_req.tp_block_size * s_packet_req.tp_block_nr;
    
        /* set packet loss option */
        tmp = mode_loss;
        if (setsockopt(fd_socket, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_LOSS, (char *)&tmp, sizeof(tmp))<0)
        {
            perror("setsockopt: PACKET_LOSS");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        
        /* send TX ring request */
        if (setsockopt(fd_socket, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_TX_RING, (char *)&s_packet_req, sizeof(s_packet_req))<0)
        {
            perror("setsockopt: PACKET_TX_RING");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* change send buffer size */
        if(c_sndbuf_sz) {
            printf("send buff size = %d\n", c_sndbuf_sz);
            if (setsockopt(fd_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &c_sndbuf_sz, sizeof(c_sndbuf_sz))< 0)
            {
                perror("getsockopt: SO_SNDBUF");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    
        /* get data offset */
        data_offset = TPACKET_HDRLEN - sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll);
    
        /* mmap Tx ring buffers memory */
        ps_header_start = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_socket, 0);
        if (ps_header_start == (void*)-1)
        {
            perror("mmap");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
    
        int i,j;
        int i_index = 0;
        char * data;
        int first_loop = 1;
        struct tpacket_hdr * ps_header;
        int ec_send = 0;
 
        int i_index_start = i_index;
        
        ps_header = ((struct tpacket_hdr *)((void *)ps_header_start + (c_buffer_sz*i_index)));
        data = ((void*) ps_header) + data_offset;
        //Datagram to represent the packet
        char datagram[4096] , source_ip[32] , *pseudogram;
    
        //zero out the packet buffer
        memset (datagram, 0, 4096);
    
        //Ethernet header
        struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) datagram;
        
        //IP header
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ether_header));
    
        //TCP header
        struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ether_header) + sizeof (struct ip));
        struct sockaddr_in sin;
        struct pseudo_header psh;
    
        //some address resolution
        strcpy(source_ip , inet_ntoa(ipaddr->sin_addr));
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sin.sin_port = htons(80);
        if (fscanf(fp, "%253s", server) == 1)
            sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (server);   
        else
        {
            done = 1;
            break;
        }
                        
        //Fill in the Ethernet Header
        eh->ether_dhost[0] = arp_resp->sender_mac[0];
        eh->ether_dhost[1] = arp_resp->sender_mac[1];
        eh->ether_dhost[2] = arp_resp->sender_mac[2];
        eh->ether_dhost[3] = arp_resp->sender_mac[3];
        eh->ether_dhost[4] = arp_resp->sender_mac[4];
        eh->ether_dhost[5] = arp_resp->sender_mac[5];

        memcpy(eh->ether_shost, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, HWADDR_len);
        eh->ether_type = htons(0x0800);
                        
        //Fill in the IP Header
        iph->ihl = 5;
        iph->version = 4;
        iph->tos = 0;
        iph->tot_len = htons(sizeof (struct iphdr) + sizeof (struct tcphdr));
        iph->id = htons (54321);    //Id of this packet
        iph->frag_off = 0;
        iph->ttl = 255;
        iph->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        iph->check = 0;     //Set to 0 before calculating checksum
        iph->saddr = inet_addr ( source_ip );
        iph->daddr = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
    
        //Ip checksum
        iph->check = checksum2 (datagram + sizeof (struct ether_header), sizeof (struct iphdr));
    
        //TCP Header
        tcph->source = htons (1234);
        tcph->dest = htons (80);
        tcph->seq = 0;
        tcph->ack_seq = 0;
        tcph->doff = 5; //tcp header size
        tcph->fin=0;
        tcph->syn=1;
        tcph->rst=0;
        tcph->psh=0;
        tcph->ack=0;
        tcph->urg=0;
        tcph->window = htons (5840);    // maximum allowed window size 
        tcph->check = 0;    //leave checksum 0 now, filled later by pseudo header
        tcph->urg_ptr = 0;

        //Now the TCP checksum
        psh.source_address = inet_addr( source_ip );
        psh.dest_address = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
        psh.placeholder = 0;
        psh.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        psh.tcp_length = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    
        int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
        pseudogram = malloc(psize);
    
        memcpy(pseudogram , (char*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
        memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) , tcph , sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    
        tcph->check = checksum2(pseudogram , psize);
                        
        memcpy(data, datagram, (sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr)));
        free(pseudogram);
        len = sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
        
        i_index ++;
        if(i_index >= c_buffer_nb)
        {
            i_index = 0;
            first_loop = 0;
        }
 
        /* update packet len */
        //ps_header->tp_len = c_packet_sz;
        ps_header->tp_len = len;
        /* set header flag to USER (trigs xmit)*/
        ps_header->tp_status = TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST;
        
        //int ec_send;
        static int total=0;
        //int blocking = 1;
        
        /* send all buffers with TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST */
        /* Wait end of transfer */
        //ec_send = sendto(fd_socket,NULL,0,(blocking? 0 : MSG_DONTWAIT),(struct sockaddr *) ps_sockaddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        ec_send = sendto(fd_socket,NULL,len,MSG_DONTWAIT,(struct sockaddr *) ps_sockaddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        
        if(ec_send < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
        }
        else if ( ec_send == 0 ) {
            /* nothing to do => schedule : useful if no SMP */
            printf("Sleeping\n");
            usleep(0);
        }
        else {
            total += ec_send/(len);
            printf("send %d packets (+%d bytes)\n",total, ec_send);
            fflush(0);
        }
        //ps_header_start = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_socket, 0);
        if (munmap(ps_header_start, size) == -1)
        {
            perror("munmap");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }       
    
        close(fd_socket);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the output of `strace -c` for just over 5,000 packets sent:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 48.11    3.962165         395     10012           setsockopt
 16.69    1.374748         274      5014           mmap
 14.85    1.222565         244      5007           munmap
 10.91    0.898695         179      5016           close
  3.15    0.259055          25     10022           ioctl
  2.04    0.167613          33      5016           socket
  1.70    0.139623          27      5008           sendto
  1.41    0.116430          23      5025           write
  1.14    0.093826          18      5008           bind
  0.01    0.000505          26        19           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           pread64
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           recvfrom
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           recvmsg
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           openat
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           newfstatat
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           prlimit64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrandom
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    8.235225         149     55182         2 total
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm . Did you tried to use `TCP_NODELAY`? (or possibly `TCP_QUICKACK`)

Comment: @JérômeRichard Just tried ```TCP_NODELAY```. It made no difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JérômeRichard actually I get a ```setsockopt: Protocol not available``` error on attempting to set that option. Perhaps that's why I was getting no difference. Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: It might be because of the raw sockets (the OS does not recognize the option because the TCP protocol is not set for the socket). But if so, I am wondering if the OS stack would use the standard TCP path... For the timings, I am surprised by the high cost of the `setsockopt` and it would be interesting to know which one is slow. The rest seems normal to me (syscalls are expensive). The point is creating/configuring/clearing a new socket of each packet is really not efficient. However, IDK if they can be (partially) *recycled*.

Comment: My understanding of ```PF_PACKET``` is that you are communicating directly with the NIC. You are completely bypassing the TCP/IP stack and therefore need to supply all the ethernet, TCP and IP headers yourself. I'm not sure if sockets can be recycled either. All my attempts so far have been unsuccessful. There doesn't seem to be much information out there about ```PF_PACKET``` programming.

Comment: Are you going to implement(simulate) TCP stack in a userland to make "an attempt to connect to multiple servers in a high performance manner" ? This does not look like performance improvement to me at all. I suggest to use standard TCP ```connect``` in an non-blocking manner with corresponding ```select``` on multiple sockets (which are in connection handshake state). Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15438408/12396017

Comment: Have you looked at [raw IP sockets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html)? That should  remove the need to find the router's IP address, and remove the need to deal with MAC addresses at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow the code correctly, you're redoing a ton of work for every IP address that doesn't need to be redone. Every time through the main loop you're:

- creating a new packet socket
- binding it
- setting up a tx packet ring buffer
- mmap'ing it
- sending a single packet
- unmapping
- closing the socket

That's a huge amount of work you're causing the system to do for one packet.

You should only create one packet socket at the beginning, set up the tx buffer and mmap once, and leave it open until the program is done. You can send any number of packets through the interface without closing/re-opening.

This is why your top time users are `setsockopt`, `mmap`, `unmap`, etc. All of those operations are heavy in the kernel.

Also, the point of `PACKET_TX_RING` is that you can set up a large buffer and create one packet after another within the buffer *without* making a `send` system call for each packet. By using the packet header's `tp_status` field you're telling the kernel that this frame is ready to be sent. You then advance your pointer within the ring buffer to the next available slot and build another packet. When you have no more packets to build (or you've filled the available space in the buffer [i.e. wrapped around to your oldest still-in-flight frame]), you can then make one `send/sendto` call to tell the kernel to go look at your buffer and (start) sending all those packets.

You can then start building more packets (being careful to ensure they are not still in use by the kernel -- through the `tp_status` field).

That said, if this were a project I were doing, I would simplify a lot - at least for the first pass: create a packet socket, bind it to the interface, build packets one at a time, and use `send` once per frame (i.e. not bothering with `PACKET_TX_RING`). If (and only if) performance requirements are so tight that it needs to send faster would I bother setting up and using the ring buffer. I doubt you'll need that. This should go a ton faster without the excess `setsockopt` and `mmap` calls.

Finally, a non-blocking socket is only useful if you have something else to do while you're waiting. In this case, if you have the socket set to be non-blocking and the packet can't be sent because the call *would block*, the `send` call will fail and if you don't do something about that (enqueue the packet somewhere, and retry later, say), the packet will be lost. In this program, I can't see any benefit whatsoever to using a non-blocking socket. If the socket blocks, it's because the device transmit queue is full. After that, there's no point in you continuing to produce packets to be sent, you won't be able send those packets either. Much simpler to just block at that point until the queue drains.

Comment: I've implemented most of your suggestions and posted in a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660468/why-is-sendto-returning-zero-with-raw-sockets The problem now is that ```sendto``` keeps returning zero on every iteration of the main ```while``` loop except the first. I have no idea why this is happening. Can you solve it?

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer. Looks like I've finally found someone who knows what he's talking about. The reason I started this was because of a comment on another ```epoll``` related question. I wonder if you could solve that one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584121/why-doesnt-my-epoll-based-program-improve-performance-by-increasing-the-number